# JQuery - Changing a button's font-weight without changing its size

Tags: jquery, css

When I change a button's font-weight, the size will also be changed. My problem is that I can't give the button a predefined size, so I tried to fix it with `.css('width','-=4px');`

But that will not work. Hope somebody can help me.

**HTML**

```
<input id="b1" type="button" value="Hello world" />
<input id="b2" type="button" value="Blubba blib" />
<input id="b3" type="button" value="Bl" />
<input id="b4" type="button" value="Blubba 55" />
```

**JS**

```
$('input:button').click(function() {

  $('*').css('font-weight','normal');  
  $(this).css('font-weight','bold');    
  $(this).css('width','-=4px');      

});
```

**Exmaple**
http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/618/

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

Just add some extra width before making it bold.

```
$('input:button').width(function(){
    return $(this).outerWidth() + 20;
}).click(function() {
    $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold').siblings().css('font-weight', 'normal');
});
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/djhRB/

there you go.

Comment: Hi Stefanvds, your solution did not work :( -> http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/626/

Comment: I see what you did there - but no, it's not the extra width that's making them hold their size - it's the fact that you're assigning them a fixed width. If you remove the `+ 20px` it'll work just the same. It's basically my solution, but better (though less flexible, if you want to change the contents of the button dynamically), so +1 there. I'm also updating your solution to one that's more efficient, hope you won't mind

Answer (score 5):

Before going anywhere with this code you have to give the buttons some padding, so that when the text inside them expand, they don't overflow. This code uses `.outerWidth` to obtain the correct width and adjust the button accordingly.

```
$('input:button').click(function() {
    var w = $(this).outerWidth();

    $(this).css({
        'font-weight': 'bold',
        'width': w
    }).siblings().css({
        'width': 'auto',
        'font-weight': 'normal'
    });
});
```

See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/CegfY/2

Answer (score 2):

I got Ur Problem

and U can find out the width of the button and decrease width of that button like bellow.

```
            $('*').css('font-weight', 'normal');
            $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
            var wdth = $(this).width();
            wdth = wdth - 4;
            $(this).css({ width: wdth+'px' });
```

So When You ll click that button it ll find out the width of button and 
Decrease the width.

ultimately You can check the font-wight attribute and make it decrease or increase alternately according to your requirement.

Also you can make the size percentage to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set a larger size to your buttons from the start, so that when the text gets bold the size does not change.

Comment: Can you give me a jsfiddle exmaple please?